# How to save downloaded image to gallery as today's media?

Tags: android, kotlin, gallery, media, android-download-manager

i am downloading an image from url using Download Manager.
for example i upload to server image from my gallery taken 1 month ago.
then i download it via Download Manager. When it's saved to gallery it displayed on 1 month ago's media. But as it's newly downloaded file it has to be today's media.

I tried to change last modified date of file. Also tried changing ExIf DateTime tag.
Still it is not displayed as latest image on gallery (today's media).
any ideas on this?

Comment: You cannot save to gallery. You can only let the download manager save to a storage location. Tell which one.

Comment: `it displayed on 1 month ago's media` Which app is displaying?

Comment: And where do you have a gallery?

Comment: @blackapps using something like this
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png"
            )

but still, why doesn't it display it as today's media? As expected if it is downloaded now, it is today's media.Under the hood it keeps created date of its own. And in gallery order it becomes to wrong place

Comment: @blackapps its default samsung phone's Gallery, like each android device has.
Overall i can give example from telegram and whatsapp. When you use "save to gallery" functionality it saves media to gallery as today's media ( media's time handled as sent time actually under the hood)